# Are there any legal requirements when deploying code with the youtube api?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We are currently completing a .Net application that uses the YouTube API. The API DLLs are loaded from NuGet packages, all working fine. To be legally on the safe side, do we need to include any further files in our installer, e.g. an API readme or a term license document?
The NuGet packages only provide the DLLs.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Google .net client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) is covered under the [Apache licence](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/LICENSE) to my knowledge there is nothing that you need to include in your project to use it.